# Where are the parameters coming from in my updateState reactjs function?

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, parameters

I'm just starting JS and React using the fullstack.io book.

In the book, there is a section of code:

```
updateState: function () {
    const products = Data.sort((a, b) => {
        return b.votes - a.votes;
}
```

Now everytime the updateState function is called in the code samples, there are no parameters passed in... so how would the "a" & "b" parameters used in the Data.sort be populated?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what `Data` is but let's assume it's an array.

[`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is a function that takes a comparator callback function `(a, b) => { ... }`.
The function compares elements `a` and `b`.
If the function returns a number less than 0, `a` comes before `b` (ascending order).
Otherwise `b` comes before `a` (descending order).

**The key takeaway is that `a` and `b` are passed by `sort` under the hood. You only need to worry about providing the callback which determines the sort order.**

For example:

```
let arr = [2, 4, 7, 1]

arr.sort((a, b) => a - b) // => [1, 2, 4, 7]

arr.sort((a, b) => b - a) // => [7, 4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. That clarifies it for me. Just wasn't sure where the values were coming from. And yes, you were correct in your assumption - it was a JS array. I appreciate your time.